# How to accumulate data for the previous x number of days

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, date

**Q:** For the argument of the question, say today is 26/03/15. How can I 'accumulate' data for the last 5 days.

---

*But these dates are just an example*. Ideally I would like to be able to accumulate data for the last *x* days, once accumulated I will email accumulated information off. I will do this process once every *z* weeks via crontabs aid.

This is the code:

```
awk_variables=`echo "$line" | awk -F, '( $13 == "*OUT*" )||( $13 == "*IN*" ){print $1,$5,$10,$12,$13}' my_file.csv > /directory/some_directory/non_sorted_filtered.csv`

cat /directory/some_directory/non_sorted_filtered.csv | while read line
do

        awk_variables="$line"
        awk_variables_array=($awk_variables)

        awk_time=${awk_variables_array[0]}
        awk_container_ID=${awk_variables_array[1]}
        awk_scan_count=${awk_variables_array[2]}
        awk_part_number=${awk_variables_array[3]}
        awk_direction==${awk_variables_array[4]}

        awk_part_number_edited="${awk_part_number:3}"
        awk_direction_edited="${awk_direction:1}"

        awk_date=@''$awk_time
        date=`date -d $awk_date +"%d/%m/%Y"`


        echo -e "Date:$date   Scan No:$awk_scan_count   Part No:$awk_part_number_edited  Direction:$awk_direction_edited"


done
```

This is the output:

```
Date:19/03/2015   Scan No:12   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:19/03/2015   Scan No:13   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:19/03/2015   Scan No:14   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:19/03/2015   Scan No:17   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:19/03/2015   Scan No:18   Part No:WTTO275  Direction:*OUT*
Date:19/03/2015   Scan No:19   Part No:WTTO275  Direction:*OUT*
Date:19/03/2015   Scan No:20   Part No:WTTO275  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:22   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:23   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:24   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:25   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:26   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:24/03/2015   Scan No:37   Part No:WTTO523  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:43   Part No:WTTO548  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:44   Part No:SP-TMX6BP  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:45   Part No:WTTO548  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:49   Part No:02102  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:50   Part No:02103  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:51   Part No:02118  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:52   Part No:02132  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:53   Part No:02133  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:54   Part No:02134  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:55   Part No:02135  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:56   Part No:19178  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:57   Part No:19179  Direction:*OUT*
```

So I would like to send the follwoing data:

```
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:22   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:23   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:24   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:25   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:20/03/2015   Scan No:26   Part No:XXXX1234567  Direction:*OUT*
Date:24/03/2015   Scan No:37   Part No:WTTO523  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:43   Part No:WTTO548  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:44   Part No:SP-TMX6BP  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:45   Part No:WTTO548  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:49   Part No:02102  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:50   Part No:02103  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:51   Part No:02118  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:52   Part No:02132  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:53   Part No:02133  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:54   Part No:02134  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:55   Part No:02135  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:56   Part No:19178  Direction:*OUT*
Date:25/03/2015   Scan No:57   Part No:19179  Direction:*OUT*
```

**NB:** the number of scans/day will vary. Somedays it might be 100 (for example) some days it will be 0.

Comment: What are you doing there hombre ? Instead of using `awk` to process your csv file, you're using that `cat squeeze | while read wise` which is prolly a hundred times slower (and error prone) + a whole block of assignments and substitutions just to format some fields... Here, play with this and try to figure out what it does: `echo "1426815663,12,H08W2345678,*OUT**" | awk -F, '{print "Date:"strftime("%d/%m/%y",$1),"Scan No:"$2,"Part No:"substr($3, 4),"Direction:"substr($4, 1, length($4)-1)}' OFS='\t'`

Comment: As to the date, you could use something like this in your script: `prevdays=$(date -d'5 days ago' +"Date:%d/%m/%Y")` so the stuff you need is from the first line that matches `^$prevdays` up to the last line.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a hint than a solution. IIRC you can use the `ISO 8601` date format and a `string compare`. Something like this might work for you:

```
iso_moment=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" -d "-5 days")
iso_date=$(date -d $awk_date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

if [[ "${iso_date}" > "${iso_moment}" ]]
then
    echo -e "Date:$date   Scan No:$awk_scan_count   Part No:$awk_part_number_edited  Direction:$awk_direction_edited"
fi
```